# Get string of objects when get json string from file get contents (php)

Tags: php, json, youtube

I have following code to get json string from YouTube:

$dataSnippet = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=jZT82WmOTkw&key=[api-key]');

This is the content (not all of it):

> string(3252) "{  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",  "etag":
>   "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/wo842EqE4etxOSsLdlZIaoKM8M0\"", 
>   "pageInfo": {   "totalResults": 1,   "resultsPerPage": 1  },  "items":
>   [   {    "kind": "youtube#video",    "etag":
>   "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/HNnm6NCNPTGVCQmzWqpMBzSi9S8\"",
>   "id": "Mpxr7Rc0ycQ",    "snippet": {
>       "publishedAt": "2018-07-18T11:29:51.000Z",
>       "channelId": "UC8ezvxw6dD3dF5Xu9Aw7icA",
>       "title": "5 Weird Things Caught on Security Cameras & CCTV #2",
>       "description": "description",
>       "thumbnails": {
>        "default": {
>         "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mpxr7Rc0ycQ/default.jpg",
>         "width": 120,
>         "height": 90
>        },
>        "medium": {
>         "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mpxr7Rc0ycQ/mqdefault.jpg",
>         "width": 320,
>         "height": 180
>        },
>        "high": {
>         "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mpxr7Rc0ycQ/hqdefault.jpg",
>         "width": 480,
>         "height": 360
>        },
>        "standard": {
>         "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mpxr7Rc0ycQ/sddefault.jpg",
>         "width": 640,
>         "height": 480
>        }, ......

But when i put a json_decode (assoc: true) over it I get this:

> array(4) {   ["kind"]=>   string(25) "youtube#videoListResponse"
>   ["etag"]=>   string(57)
>   ""XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/PPyttIkZuikajCWylsl_R32g_pE""
>   ["pageInfo"]=>   array(2) {
>       ["totalResults"]=>
>       int(1)
>       ["resultsPerPage"]=>
>       int(1)   }   ["items"]=>   array(1) {
>       [0]=>
>       string(8) "Array(4)"   } }

especially this part is strange:

> ["items"]=>   array(1) {
>       [0]=>
>       string(8) "Array(4)"   } }

How can I get a array with objects? Tried many things without a result.

Comment: Can you show the whole (relevant) code?

Comment: Relevant code? This is all. Or do you mean the whole json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're using `json_decode($val, assoc: true)`

From the php documentation:

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

So, just don't use true, and it should treat things the way you want.

---

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/wo842EqE4etxOSsLdlZIaoKM8M0",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 1
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/HNnm6NCNPTGVCQmzWqpMBzSi9S8",
            "id": "Mpxr7Rc0ycQ",
            "snippet": {
                "publishedAt": "2018-07-18T11:29:51.000Z",
                "channelId": "UC8ezvxw6dD3dF5Xu9Aw7icA",
                "title": "5 Weird Things Caught on Security Cameras & CCTV #2",
                "description": "description",
                "thumbnails": {
                    "default": {
                        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mpxr7Rc0ycQ/default.jpg",
                        "width": 120,
                        "height": 90
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mpxr7Rc0ycQ/mqdefault.jpg",
                        "width": 320,
                        "height": 180
                    },
                    "high": {
                        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mpxr7Rc0ycQ/hqdefault.jpg",
                        "width": 480,
                        "height": 360
                    },
                    "standard": {
                        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mpxr7Rc0ycQ/sddefault.jpg",
                        "width": 640,
                        "height": 480
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}';

$val = json_decode($json);
print_r($val);
```

Converts to:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [kind] => youtube#videoListResponse
    [etag] => XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/wo842EqE4etxOSsLdlZIaoKM8M0
    [pageInfo] => stdClass Object
        (
            [totalResults] => 1
            [resultsPerPage] => 1
        )

    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [kind] => youtube#video
                    [etag] => XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/HNnm6NCNPTGVCQmzWqpMBzSi9S8
                    [id] => Mpxr7Rc0ycQ
                    [snippet] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2018-07-18T11:29:51.000Z
                            [channelId] => UC8ezvxw6dD3dF5Xu9Aw7icA
                            [title] => 5 Weird Things Caught on Security Cameras & CCTV #2
                            [description] => description
                            [thumbnails] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [default] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mpxr7Rc0ycQ/default.jpg
                                            [width] => 120
                                            [height] => 90
                                        )

                                    [medium] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mpxr7Rc0ycQ/mqdefault.jpg
                                            [width] => 320
                                            [height] => 180
                                        )

                                    [high] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mpxr7Rc0ycQ/hqdefault.jpg
                                            [width] => 480
                                            [height] => 360
                                        )

                                    [standard] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Mpxr7Rc0ycQ/sddefault.jpg
                                            [width] => 640
                                            [height] => 480
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

`stdClass` being PHP's internal equivelant of a generic `object`.

Comment: It wil not. Because when I remove True I get this:

object(stdClass)#746 (1) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(8) "stdClass"
}

Comment: I think it has something to do with the  "[ ]" in the json file.

Comment: I just added an example doing this, with your example JSON, and what it converts to. Can you please explain how `items` is not an array of objects to me?